# Optimize away memory loads by jit-compiling value as immediate

Tags: optimization, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization, jit, trace

Suppose we have a following code-snippet in some abstract programming language:

```
map<string, int> user_settings;
//somewhere at run-time user_settings are populated
for(i=0; i < 1000000000000; i++) {
    if (user_settings["do_stuff"] == 1) { do some stuff... }
    else { do other stuff }
}
```

The problem here is that we will do a lot of loads inside the loop at runtime of some thing, that is "runtime constant" (namely, some value of a user-setting). There is a potential to supply the value via immediate load or even completely optimize away useless branch and use only code of needed then-else-branch.
Are there systems/programming languages/jit compilers that perform such optimizations? Only related work I could find was the thesis of some MIT guy: http://groups.csail.mit.edu/cag/rio/josh-meng-thesis.pdf
***P.S.*** I am not asking to optimize ***this*** code. I know, that you can load the value beforehand, which will be loaded to a local register. There are sometimes cases, where you cannot perform such an "optimization" by hand.

Comment: There isn’t even the requirement for the result to be a “runtime constant”—all that matters is that the loop body doesn’t change it. Moving such invariant evaluations out of the loop in pretty much standard for every optimizer.

Comment: @Holger could you provide examples? because as far as I could find only CS research jit compilers do that, but no production-ready language

Comment: I’m not sure which kind of optimization you assume to be an obstacle. Recognizing that the expressions are loop invariant requires inlining of their code, which is why inlining is performed aggressively, e.g. inside a JVM. The rest is state-of-the-art, e.g. [The Hotspot whitepaper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/whitepaper-135217.html) says “*The optimizer performs all the classic optimizations, including dead code elimination, loop invariant hoisting, common subexpression elimination, constant propagation, global value numbering, and global code motion*”…

Comment: Okay, maybe you are already assuming this is not possible. But with some Alias Analysis to make sure that `user_settings["do_stuff"]` is only accessed and not modified inside the loop combined with Loop-invariant code motion should pull that right out of the loop. This is a really common optimization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One neat approach that is for example used in dynamic linkers might be useful here:

Make your compiler generate the dynamic code so it knows who called it.

That way, if the dynamic code finds that the data it receives can never change, it can just rewrite the code at the call site. So instead of a `CALL get_user_setting "do_stuff"` it will replace the instruction with `PUSH int 1` or whatever, and maybe a few `NOP`s to pad out the size of the CALL instruction.

Dynamic linkers often do this. The first time you try to call a dynamically linked function, they actually jump into the loader. It loads the actual function, then rewrites the CALL instruction so it calls the loaded function instead of the routine to load the function. Any future calls then don't have to do the look-up a second time. (I blogged about this [here](https://orangejuiceliberationfront.com/building-a-loader/))

Answer (score 0):

A good compiler optimization step would ***potentially*** preload and test "do stuff" from the dictionary and drop the iterations all together. It would do this if it could determine that there is no side-effect which would change the value of "do stuff" in the dictionary.

If you are writing your own compiler, there are massive amounts of optimization techniques. Of course they will vary based on whether you are developing an imperative type of language or functional and the `tenets` that go along with them.

For example, in most functional languages I am assured that the content of most module declared data types (lists, sets, maps) will not change (are persistent) over time. In some cases, these languages support side-effect or mutative capabilities in which case your optimizations must consider that as well.